# Simple/ish command

Tags: sql, command, view

Which join do you use to select data from parent and child table, where the parent table may contain no child data?

Comment: And what is your question?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I upvoted this because in spite of the horrible way it's worded, this is one of the most common questions in all of SQL.

Comment: I know I'm being picky but the plural of property is properties :-)

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry im really not good at sql so not very good at wording my explanation! I have tried an inner join but the only information I can display is the property that has a lease associated, I wish to display property details which do not have a lease. Each lease has a primary key of LEASEID and a foreign key to link the propery as PROPERTYID

Comment: @penfold I didn't realize how bad I wrote and explained this until after, sql is fuzzling my mind!

Comment: Dude, that's fine, you're new! SQL is hard to learn correctly, and you're putting in an effort which is great. You have to learn some time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! SQL takes a bit of work to get your head around it. At least it did with me!

Comment: @user2325417 . . . BTW, I didn't downvvote you.  I couldn't tell whether you wanted information on how to create a command-line that runs SQL or the syntax for the query itself.  Good luck learning SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thankyou, I have some solutions now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is more properly stated as this:

> How to find items in the master table which don't have any items in the child table?

That is a very common question in SQL, and there is a known solution... this works in T-SQL (you need to always say what you're using)

```
select m.master_data, c.child_data
from master_table m
left outer join child_table c 
    on m.ID = c.ID
where c.child_data IS NULL
```

When there is nothing in the child table, the OUTER join produces nulls in the child table columns, so you just show the rows with nulls in the child table and that's it. You don't show any columns from the child table in your result.

Comment: This is the same as an answer which you accepted, expect I provided the explanation. So is the one below this. Like I said, it's a well-known solution.

Comment: Sorry have no idea how to work the site just yet!, accepted yours & thanks for the help

Comment: That isn't what I was getting at but thanks. I meant, you don't need to test all of these answers, they are all the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of finding properties that don't have a lease.

1. Use a sub-query in the where clause

   ```
   select *
   from propertys
   where propertys.propertyID not in (select propertyID from lease);
   ```
2. Alternatively you can use a left join with a null check in the where clause

   ```
   select *
   from propertys
   left join lease on lease.propertyID = propertys.propertysID
   where lease.leaseID is null;
   ```

Comment: Tried the second one & it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
p.* 
FROM
Property p
LEFT JOIN Lease l ON p.propertyid = l.propertyid
WHERE l.propertyid IS NULL
```

Comment: Thankyou I've been given a few different solutions and giving them all ago!